# Can't boot into Windows 7 after installing 11.10

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, grub2, installation

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 beta2 along with windows 7 but after installation I am not getting the boot menu and I straight away boot into Ubuntu. kindly help..!!!

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix for many dual boot problems is updating your Grub (Grub is the bootloader - GRand Unified Bootloader)

Try this:

Open a terminal by pressing **ctrl+alt+t** or open your unity dash and start typing "**terminal**"
Type/copy:

```
    sudo update-grub
```

That should add the windows entry, let us know if not and we'll try some other options.

**grub-customizer** is a good gui package to use, but this should do the same automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have a situation similar to you from what I can gather from you. I installed Ubuntu on to a HP desktop, and after the HP splash screen and where the GRUB screen should be is nothing but a blank screen with my monitors screen resolution information. After waiting a little bit it will boot to Ubuntu.
However, I can boot into Windows by pressing the down arrow (I think I press it about 6 times to be sure) after the HP splash screen and during the blank screen with the monitor information. That is were GRUB should have been shown, and that is where I blindly select Windows (not really an issue for me because rarely ever need Windows and I mean rarely).
Perhaps this could be the same issue you have run into as well, and maybe this might solve your problem about being able to boot into Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the GRUB2 configuration. For an easy GUI, install package **grub-customizer** and open it (will ask admin access). Then:

- Verify that **os-prober** is checked, that is the GRUB2 component that find other OS
- click Preferences and verify that "Show menu" is checked and that wait time is enough to see it.

For info: [Grub-Customizer launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)